# Binding input controls to currently selected item in observable collection MVVM approach

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, listbox

I wanted to know if there was a way to bind the single currently selected item within a listbox to a set of textboxes and buttons in WPF.

Say I have a listbox like so

```
<ListBox Margin="5"
 ItemsSource="{Binding Tags}"></ListBox>
```

And a view model like so

```
public sealed class HomeViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<ViewModels.TagViewModel> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

with each `TagViewModel` in that observable collection looking like so

```
public class TagViewModel
{

    public ICommand SaveNewTag { get; set; }
    public ICommand DeleteCurrentTag { get; set; }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

how would I *on select of an item in the listbox* bind to that specific item's Name attribute only and bind it's commands to two buttons that I have using an MVVM approach?

```
<TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               Margin="0 0 0 40">Tags</TextBlock>
                        <Button Margin="0 0 0 10"
                                Command="{Binding SaveNewTag}">Add</Button>
                        <Button Margin="0 0 0 50"
                                Command="{Binding DeleteCurrentTag}">Delete</Button>
                        <TextBox MinWidth="200" ToolTip="Tag you want to add"
                                 Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Can you provide more explanation? What's the last xaml part file? Is that your `DataTemplate` in your `ListBox`?

Comment: No it is not. My list box is basically showing a string per item so I don't need a data template. This is some xaml that is outside of my listbox. I basically want functionality that when an item in my listbox is clicked, it displays the selected item's `name` property within the above textbox. `Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

```
<ListBox Margin="5" x:Name="tagsListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Tags}"></ListBox>
```

I'd wrap the this control

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=tagsListBox,Path=SelectedItem.DataContext}">
 <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Margin="0 0 0 40">Tags</TextBlock>
 <Button Margin="0 0 0 10"
         Command="{Binding SaveNewTag}">Add</Button>
 <Button Margin="0 0 0 50"
         Command="{Binding DeleteCurrentTag}">Delete</Button>
 <TextBox MinWidth="200" ToolTip="Tag you want to add"
          Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Basically, you can do the `ElementName` binding to update the `Display View` that you have based on the `SelectedItem`. I just wrapped it in `StackPanel` so that the children inherits the `DataContext` value. Your choice if you want to set the `DataContext` for each child control.

Comment: Thanks! Attached properties.. I have been away from WPF for too long.